# Extracting Date value from DateTime column

Tags: python

Using Python how to extract the Date values from a DateTime column?

[image]

Like this example using SQL:

```sql
SELECT 
    CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) date;
```

Comment: What does this question have to do with respect to Python? What kind of file or data-structure is the table in the screenshot from?

Comment: Please include the python code necessary to reproduce your problem. Take these guidelines into consideration: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`Pandas DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) and read the sql table using the [`pandas.read_sql()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html) function, given your SQL connection:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_sql('select referrer_col, timestamp_col from my_table', your_connection)
```

Then convert the timestamp column using [`Series.dt.date`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.date.html)

```
df['date_only'] = df['timestamp_col'].dt.date
```

Answer (score 0):

Having a string (datestring in this example) that represents each value of that column, you can use the strptime method of datetime module:

```
import datetime as dt

datestring = "2016-02-05 00:48:23"
date = dt.datetime.strptime(datestring, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").date()
```

Then you can have access to the day, month and year as follows:

```
day = date.day
month = date.month
year = date.year
```